# Compare values from a dictionary of dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

i have this nested dictionary that i want to check to see if the values match and if they dont return the values.

```
dict_test = {'sct2': {(5, 5, 0): [1, 2, 3]}, 'sct1': {(5, 5, 0): [1, 2, 4]}}
```

So basically from iterating thru dict_test i will be comparing the values from 'sct2' and 'sct1' dictionaries and see if they match, if they dont i will print out the value that didnt match. I can do this if i split into 2 dictionaries and than compare them

```
test1=dict_test['sct2']
test2=dict_test['sct1']
```

and than i can just compare the 2 dictionaries and do something like this :

```
mismatch = [val for val in test1.itervalues() if not val in test2.itervalues()]
```

which will return [1,2,4] although i would want it to return 4 instead of the list

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this and without having to create 2 dictionaries, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So you want to compare ```[1,2,3]``` to ```[1,2,4]```?

Comment: Do you only want to compare entries with an identical tuple key?

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to use test2, but does use the undefined y; that doesn't sound right...

Comment: Sorry, it should be test2 and not y, have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [minus operator of sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference), which gives the difference of two sets. For clarity you could use the difference method instead which also gives the difference.

```
mismatch = list(filter(set(s2)-set(s1) for s1 in dict_test["sct2"].values()\
            for s2 in dict_test["sct1"].values()))
```

Comment: minus operator requires explicit conversion to a set.

Comment: @IceArdor True; I thought the minus operator and the difference method were the same. However, the difference method implicitly converts `s1` into a set, while the minus operator doesn't. Will file a bug report (or an enhancement request) about that.

Comment: There's no need to convert the keys in `s2` to a set here... use `s2.viewkeys() - s1` to utilise the dict view object whose `-` *will* work with arbitrary iterables.

Comment: I also wouldn't bother making an enhancement request - the operator versions of the functions for `set` are deliberately designed to not take iterables of non-set compatible types.

Comment: @JonClements Reference for it being deliberately designed? Regarding the other comment, `s2` isn't a dictionary, it's a list. Going to bed.

Comment: @RamchandraApte PEP-20: "Explicit is better than implicit". The meaning of the + operator is different for sets and lists, so I would expect explicit conversion. Read the docs for `set`. This is no bug, it is by design.

Comment: @RamchandraApte ahh good point... my bad - misread it... I'll see if I can dig up the reference

Comment: From [the official set docs - next paragraph after this link](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set.copy): *Note, the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(), difference(), and symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset() methods will accept any iterable as an argument. In contrast, their operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets. This precludes error-prone constructions like set('abc') & 'cbs' in favor of the more readable set('abc').intersection('cbs').*

Answer (score 0):

Without a better idea of the problem you're trying to solve, here's code that would return `((3,4))` based on your `test_dict`. Please clearly state your problem, restrictions, requirements more clearly if you want an answer that better addresses your problem.

```
def diffList(a,b):
    '''Assumption: a and b are same length
    Returns non-matching ordered pairs of a and b
    '''
    return filter(lambda ai, bi: ai != bi, zip(a,b)))

outerKeyPairs = [(outerKeyA, outerKeyB) for outerKeyA in test_dict for outerKeyB in test_dict if outerKeyA > outerKeyB]
for outerKeyA, outerKeyB in outerKeyPairs:
    for innerKey in test_dict[outerKeyA]:
        if innerKey in test_dict[outerKeyB]:
            yield diffList(test_dict[outerKeyA][innerKey], test_dict[outerKeyB][innerKey])
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly clean way to do this would be:

```
def diff_list(l1, l2):
    s = set(l2)
    return [i for i in l1 if i not in s]

{t:diff_list(l1, test2[t]) for (t,l1) in test1.iteritems()}
```

This produces a mapping of each differing key with a list of the values that are missing:

```
{(5, 5, 0): [3]}
```

---

Note that the logic for `diff_list` above assumes that you don't care about the position and quantity of items in each list. If this is important, `diff_list` can be implemented as:

```
def diff_list(l1, l2):
    return {i: (v[0], v[1]) for i,v in enumerate(map(None, l1, l2)) if v[0] != v[1]}
```

Using this approach, you get the following output:

```
>>> test1  # Here's what test1 looks like
{(5, 5, 0): [1, 2, 3]}

>>> test2  # Here's what test2 looks like
{(5, 5, 0): [1, 2, 4]}

>>> {t:diff_list(l1, test2[t]) for (t,l1) in test1.iteritems()} # Getting the difference
{(5, 5, 0): {2: (3, 4)}}
```

That is to say, you get a dictionary containing every differing key in `test1` and `test2`, mapped to a dictionary that contains every index that was different, and the values at that index in both of the differing lists.